# Firebase Storage NoSuchMethod exception when downloading an image URL

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage

I'm trying to download the URL from an image named art0.jpg that i have uploaded to Cloud Storage. The bucket has two folders and the image is located inside a folder called Arts. Whenever i run my app, it just crashes and the exception/trace i get is the following :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.gammapi.dokkancardsonline-dcDgng_RjmbeJTVo_mDVqA==/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.GetDownloadUrlTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.5:71)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Part that causes the crash:

```
storageRef.child("Arts/art0.jpg")
    .downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
    //GlideApp.with(cntxt).load(uri).into(imageView)
    Log.d(TAG,"$uri")
}.addOnFailureListener {
    Log.d(TAG,"ERROR DOWNLOADING IMAGE")
}
```

app.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "id"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    kapt 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'

    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.1"
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Now i looked at various posts (there are a ton i know) but despite implementing every dependency they mentioned, i still couldn't get it to work. Which method is the compiler not able to locate?  If it's the `getToken(Z)` one, since that's an internal one what can i do to overcome this issue?

Comment: FYI backtick quotes are use only for code snippets on Stack Overflow, not for general text emphasis.

Comment: @DougStevenson I didn't know that, thank you very much. I'll make sure i never use it that way again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a very old version of com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage.  The latest at this moment [according to GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android) is 6.0.2.

Comment: This solved it! I didn't think that i could be using older versions of these libraries. Usually gradle tells me that i can upgrade but in this case, there were no indications. Do you happen to know why that is? Should i learn to check manually about the latest versions of libraries just in case?

Comment: I've not found Android Studio to be terribly good about noticing updates.  I always check in from time to time to get latest.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a ton. I always thought Android Studio would notify me every time. I'll make sure to start checking manually from time to time.